# How to automatically put text or job commands into `crontab` file?

Tags: cron, syslinux

I create machine `VM` with terraform, I have 3 job that should be create into `crontab` file when server creation.
These 3 jobs must be run automatically inside crontab file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project I created a script.sh file for my corns that I wanted to run when Terraform provisioning machine, then I put that on remote-exec.

The script.sh contains below code for one crone, for more crones we need another one.

`lines2="*/1 * * * * /bin/bash path/to/file/on/machine_mgmt.sh >> path/to/file/on/machine-log.txt" ( crontab -u root -l; echo "$lines2" ) | crontab -u root -`

Answer (score 1):

You could be try using cloud-init while boot strapping your image. Use cloud-config write_files module to create a cron entry file in /etc/cron.d/ and you need to setup [USER] as user you want to execute your cron jobs.

```
 #cloud-config 

 write_files:
 - owner: root:root
   path: /etc/cron.d/your_cronjob
   content: * */2 * * * [USER] du -s test/
```